# How to obtain the End Frame value to use it in Geometry Nodes?

Tags: geometry-nodes, drivers

I've been looking for a node or way to get the end frame value, this because of the tutorials I've seen, they usually use this value as a way to make a loop and then there's a smooth transition between the final and first frame, is there a way to do this?

This way I could create a custom group node and automatically fill the value instead of manually changing the value of the total frames each time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To do this, you have to copy the **full data path** by right clicking on the Blender interface

You can for example go to the Scene panel, Output tab (right properties panel), go to Frame Range, and right click on the End slider, the required option says: Copy Full Data Path, then you create a Value node in the Geometry Nodes Workspace tab, and in the input slider where you usually place a number, you paste what you copied from the Full Data Path with a `#` appended to it, in this case `bpy.data.scenes["Scene"].frame_end` (it becomes `#bpy.data.scenes["Scene"].frame_end`), the field will turn purple and the value will be updated with the end frame value, it will not update immediately if you change the end frame again until you press play or spacebar.

Another place to obtain the value by right clicking on it, is in the timeline (Animation Workspace tab), you can right click on the End field there and click the Copy Full Data Path path option, this is the same as the End slider in Frame Range.

Output Panel:

[image: Frame Range and the End slider]

Right click on Frame End field, click Copy Full Data Path:

[image: Copy Full Data Path]

Create a Value field in Geometry Nodes, paste the path with a **#** sign before it and press enter:

[image: Paste the path]

Once the value has been copied it will turn purple:

[image: The field/slider turns purple]

Comment: Or after right clicking  on `end` in the time line you can copy it as New Driver and then paste it in Geometry Nodes into a Value Node or a Math mode.

Comment: @RaoulHATTERER if you create a proper answer I can accept yours since it seems way easier than mine, what do you say?

Comment: Regular 'paste' throws an error in the driver editor about using variables for bpy.data. Instead just right click and select 'Paste Driver' to automatically create a variable.